# Partial fraction decompositions for integral domains

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

I've recently been involved in a math conversation regarding partial fraction decompositions for rational numbers, but we seem to lack a formal definition and are unsure about whether there is some kind of uniqueness statement.

Can someone please provide a solid reference for partial fraction decompositions for integral domains, assuming that this makes sense? (This topic is mentioned ever so briefly in the Wikipedia article about PFD's, but without an existing reference.)

Comment: Does [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4656565/how-does-partial-fraction-expansion-generalize-to-fractions-of-integers-why-is) answer your question? It appears that this can be done only for Euclidean domains, in almost the same way as for polynomials.

Comment: That answer looks very helpful, thanks! (Except for its mention of the Wikipedia page, which is not.)

Comment: But I would like to see a reference to a textbook or peer-reviewed paper.

Comment: Packard and Wilson, "Partial fractions in Euclidean domains" (1989) (MR0991540)

Comment: Thank you, Dave Benson. That is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.